# Count how many objects of each value has in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
var markers = [
  {
    "type":"Chocolate",
    "name":"KitKat",
    "group":"candy",
    "icon":"candy",
    "coords":[5246,8980],
  },
  {
    "type":"Fruit",
    "name":"Orange",
    "group":"fruits",
    "icon":"fruis",
    "coords":[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    "type":"Fruit",
    "name":"Banana",
    "group":"fruits",
    "icon":"fruis",
    "coords":[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    "type":"Food",
    "name":"Rice",
    "group":"foods",
    "icon":"foods",
    "coords":[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    "type":"Food",
    "name":"Meat",
    "group":"foods",
    "icon":"foods",
    "coords":[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    "type":"Food",
    "name":"Beam",
    "group":"foods",
    "icon":"foods",
    "coords":[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    "type":"Liquid",
    "name":"Water",
    "group":"liquids",
    "icon":"liquids",
    "coords":[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    "type":"Liquid",
    "name":"Coffe",
    "group":"liquids",
    "icon":"liquids",
    "coords":[6724,9556],
  },
]
```

Which I want to count how many items each group has in this array.

I managed to count it with this:

```
var count = []

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  count[markers[i].group] = count[markers[i].group] + 1 || 1 ;
}
```

Which outputs this result:

```
count = [
candy: 1
foods: 3
fruits: 2
liquids: 2
]
```

I want to use this values in another part, and for that I need to change the array structure, to something like this:

```
count = [
{"item": "candy","qnt":1},
{"item": "foods","qnt":3},
{"item": "fruits","qnt":2},
{"item": "liquids","qnt":2}
]
```

I know that I could do something like this:

```
var total_fruits = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  if (markers[i].group == "fruits"){
    total_fruits++
  }
}
```

But imagine how many if's I will need for a group of more than 50 types...

I will use the values in the html part with the same class that the item value is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="candy">
    <span class="qnt">1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="fruits">
    <span class="qnt">2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="foods">
    <span class="qnt">3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="liquids">
    <span class="qnt">2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions or how to improve this?

Comment: In your original code, you are using an array as an object which works but it's wrong.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Isn't that what they already have (barring the incorrect use of array type)?

Comment: It would possibly be easiest to do what your already doing, and then take that resulting object, and convert it into the list of objects like you want.  So you don't have to find the element in the array for your group each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` method to return a new array with the items and quantities.

We use a ternary statement to determine if the accumulator array already contains the group type with `findIndex`. If it doesn't we push the new type with a qnt of 1, if it does we simply increment the qnt value.

```
markers.reduce((ms, m) => (ms.findIndex(o => o.item === m["group"]) > 0) ? 
(ms[ms.findIndex(o => o.item === m["group"])]["qnt"]++, ms) : 
(ms.push({  qnt: 1,  item: m["group"]}), ms), []);
```

```js
var markers=[{type:"Chocolate",name:"KitKat",group:"candy",icon:"candy",coords:[5246,8980]},{type:"Fruit",name:"Orange",group:"fruits",icon:"fruis",coords:[9012,5493]},{type:"Fruit",name:"Banana",group:"fruits",icon:"fruis",coords:[9012,5493]},{type:"Food",name:"Rice",group:"foods",icon:"foods",coords:[6724,9556]},{type:"Food",name:"Meat",group:"foods",icon:"foods",coords:[6724,9556]},{type:"Food",name:"Beam",group:"foods",icon:"foods",coords:[6724,9556]},{type:"Liquid",name:"Water",group:"liquids",icon:"liquids",coords:[6724,9556]},{type:"Liquid",name:"Coffe",group:"liquids",icon:"liquids",coords:[6724,9556]}];

let r = markers.reduce((ms, m) => (ms.findIndex(o => o.item === m["group"]) > 0) ? 
(ms[ms.findIndex(o => o.item === m["group"])]["qnt"]++, ms) : 
(ms.push({  qnt: 1,  item: m["group"]}), ms), []);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: I didn't knew the reduce method, it's a good way to solve this too. It is more faster than generating another array?

Comment: @RogerHN It technically does create another array but it may in fact be faster. The benefit is that it's innately a functional method and it doesn't pollute the global scope with unnecessary variables and operations.

Answer (score 4):

You can build the object you want in one step with `reduce()`. This will build an object keyed to `group`. To get just the array, take the `Object.values()` of that object:

```js
var markers = [{"type":"Chocolate","name":"KitKat","group":"candy","icon":"candy","coords":[5246,8980],},{"type":"Fruit","name":"Orange","group":"fruits","icon":"fruis","coords":[9012,5493],},{"type":"Fruit","name":"Banana","group":"fruits","icon":"fruis","coords":[9012,5493],},{"type":"Food","name":"Rice","group":"foods","icon":"foods","coords":[6724,9556],},{"type":"Food","name":"Meat","group":"foods","icon":"foods","coords":[6724,9556],},{"type":"Food","name":"Beam","group":"foods","icon":"foods","coords":[6724,9556],},{"type":"Liquid","name":"Water","group":"liquids","icon":"liquids","coords":[6724,9556],},{"type":"Liquid","name":"Coffe","group":"liquids","icon":"liquids","coords":[6724,9556],},]

let counts = markers.reduce((obj, {group}) => {
  if(!obj[group]) obj[group] = {"item": group, "qnt":1}  // make a count item if it doesn't exist
  else obj[group].qnt++                                  // or increment it
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(counts))
```

Answer (score 2):

The expected output is not right.An Array cannot have key & value like that. You may need an object for that.

```js
var markers = [{
    "type": "Chocolate",
    "name": "KitKat",
    "group": "candy",
    "icon": "candy",
    "coords": [5246, 8980],
  },
  {
    "type": "Fruit",
    "name": "Orange",
    "group": "fruits",
    "icon": "fruis",
    "coords": [9012, 5493],
  },
  {
    "type": "Fruit",
    "name": "Banana",
    "group": "fruits",
    "icon": "fruis",
    "coords": [9012, 5493],
  },
  {
    "type": "Food",
    "name": "Rice",
    "group": "foods",
    "icon": "foods",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Food",
    "name": "Meat",
    "group": "foods",
    "icon": "foods",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Food",
    "name": "Beam",
    "group": "foods",
    "icon": "foods",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Liquid",
    "name": "Water",
    "group": "liquids",
    "icon": "liquids",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Liquid",
    "name": "Coffe",
    "group": "liquids",
    "icon": "liquids",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
]


let count = markers.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (acc[curr.type]) {
    acc[curr.type] += 1;
  } else {
    acc[curr.type] = 1;
  }

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(count)

/* if you need an array of objects then ,instead of object ,
pass an empty array as the accumulator. Then in that 
accumulator search if the type exist using findIndex.
If it returns -1 then create a new object with 
required values and push it in the accumulator,
 else update the value of qnt at that specific index*/

let count1 = markers.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let getItemIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.item === curr.group
  });

  if (getItemIndex === -1) {
    let obj = {
      item: curr.group,
      qnt: 1
    }
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[getItemIndex].qnt += 1;
  }

  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(count1)
```

Comment: No OP's output is `count = [
candy: 1
foods: 3
fruits: 2
liquids: 2
]` , it is an array not an object

Comment: You're right, the OP's output in the question is impossible to reproduce, since there's no way to get key/value pairs to show up between square brackets like that. But the OP asks for a format with an array of objects with `{ item: name, qnt: count }`, not `{ name: count }` as your answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via `Array.reduce` to do the grouping by `group` and then use `Object.entries` with `Array.map` to get the desired output format:

```js
var data = [ { "type":"Chocolate", "name":"KitKat", "group":"candy", "icon":"candy", "coords":[5246,8980], }, { "type":"Fruit", "name":"Orange", "group":"fruits", "icon":"fruis", "coords":[9012,5493], }, { "type":"Fruit", "name":"Banana", "group":"fruits", "icon":"fruis", "coords":[9012,5493], }, { "type":"Food", "name":"Rice", "group":"foods", "icon":"foods", "coords":[6724,9556], }, { "type":"Food", "name":"Meat", "group":"foods", "icon":"foods", "coords":[6724,9556], }, { "type":"Food", "name":"Beam", "group":"foods", "icon":"foods", "coords":[6724,9556], }, { "type":"Liquid", "name":"Water", "group":"liquids", "icon":"liquids", "coords":[6724,9556], }, { "type":"Liquid", "name":"Coffe", "group":"liquids", "icon":"liquids", "coords":[6724,9556], }, ]

const group = data.reduce((r,c) => (r[c.group] = (r[c.group] || 0) + 1, r), {})
console.log(Object.entries(group).map(([k,v]) => ({ item: k, qnt: v })))
```

Comment: Good answer! It's very clear even if it uses more than one method call. I for some reason always overthink the assignment of the group `(r[c.group] || 0) + 1` is always the best way when accumulating quantities. +1

Answer (score 2):

```js
var markers = [{
    "type": "Chocolate",
    "name": "KitKat",
    "group": "candy",
    "icon": "candy",
    "coords": [5246, 8980],
  },
  {
    "type": "Fruit",
    "name": "Orange",
    "group": "fruits",
    "icon": "fruis",
    "coords": [9012, 5493],
  },
  {
    "type": "Fruit",
    "name": "Banana",
    "group": "fruits",
    "icon": "fruis",
    "coords": [9012, 5493],
  },
  {
    "type": "Food",
    "name": "Rice",
    "group": "foods",
    "icon": "foods",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Food",
    "name": "Meat",
    "group": "foods",
    "icon": "foods",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Food",
    "name": "Beam",
    "group": "foods",
    "icon": "foods",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Liquid",
    "name": "Water",
    "group": "liquids",
    "icon": "liquids",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  },
  {
    "type": "Liquid",
    "name": "Coffe",
    "group": "liquids",
    "icon": "liquids",
    "coords": [6724, 9556],
  }
];

var temp = markers.reduce( function ( results, marker ) {
  results[ marker.group ] = ( results[ marker.group ] || 0 ) + 1;
  
  return results;
}, {});

//now convert the object to a list like you want it
temp = Object.keys( temp ).map( function ( group ) {
  return { group: group, quantity: temp[ group ] };
} );

console.log( temp );
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way (in my opinion) is to use a format like `{ item: count }` which you already have except for that `count` should be an object `{}` instead of an array `[]` (see [@brk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525235/9867451)). If you want the output to be an array of objects, then just use a cache object (that will hold the index of the count object from the `count` array):

```
var count = [], cache = {};
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var marker = markers[i];
  if(cache.hasOwnProperty(marker.type)) {           // if the current marker type has already been encountered
    count[cache[marker.type]].qnt++;                // then just retrieve the count object and increment its 'qnt'
  } else {                                          // otherwise
    cache[marker.type] = count.push({               // create a count object for this type and store its index in the cache object
      type: marker.type,
      qnt: 1
    }) - 1;                                         // - 1 because 'push' returns the new array length, thus the index is 'length - 1'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count = {
  candy: 1
  foods: 3
  fruits: 2
  liquids: 2
}
```

After calculating the grouping counts from the initial data, you can send it to view to generate the html. (It is an object, not array).
When generating html, you can iterate over its properties like this:

```
//Add ul
for(var item in count) {
   //Get data and add li (item = candy, count[item] = 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your code

```
var count = {} // I made an Object out of your Array, the proper way to do this

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  count[markers[i].group] = count[markers[i].group] + 1 || 1 ;
}
```

And convert your Object into an array afterwards:

```
var finalArray = [];
for(var key in count)
  finalArray.push({item: key, qnt: count[key]});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple this way! I don't know which answer is the fastest way to do, but this way is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var markers = [{"type":"Chocolate","name":"KitKat","group":"candy","icon":"candy","coords":[5246,8980]},{"type":"Fruit","name":"Orange","group":"fruits","icon":"fruis","coords":[9012,5493]},{"type":"Fruit","name":"Banana","group":"fruits","icon":"fruis","coords":[9012,5493]},{"type":"Food","name":"Rice","group":"foods","icon":"foods","coords":[6724,9556]},{"type":"Food","name":"Meat","group":"foods","icon":"foods","coords":[6724,9556]},{"type":"Food","name":"Beam","group":"foods","icon":"foods","coords":[6724,9556]},{"type":"Liquid","name":"Water","group":"liquids","icon":"liquids","coords":[6724,9556]},{"type":"Liquid","name":"Coffe","group":"liquids","icon":"liquids","coords":[6724,9556]}]

counts = []
markers.map(marker => counts.filter(type => type.name == marker.group).length> 0 ? counts.filter(type=>type.name ==marker.group)[0].count ++ : counts.push({'name':marker.group,'count':1}));
console.log(counts);
```

This or as someone said above, using reduce also works.
This is also rather inefficient due to multiple maps and filters

Comment: My concern is performance, because the original array has more than one thousand entries, and the application has a lot of complex functions. But itt's a good way to solve too, upvoted Colby! Thank you!